# Limit of $\lim_{x\to -\infty }\left(\frac{a^x+b^x}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$ with a > 0 and b > 0

Tags: calculus

Question:

> $\lim_{x\to -\infty }\left(\frac{a^x+b^x}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$ with $a>0$ and $b>0$.$a$ and $b$ are constant.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Hint: Use sandwich theorem. Answer is min(a,b)

Comment: Maybe you could use: $$e^{\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\frac{a^x+b^x}{2}\right)}\geqslant e^{\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\sqrt{a^xb^x}\right)}=e^{\lim_{x\to-\infty}\ln\left(\sqrt{ab}\right)}=\sqrt{ab}$$

Comment: @user600016, then, if $b\gt a$, $\sqrt{ab}\gt a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I have solved the problem, I think I should post the answers and thank everyone for their help.

> $\lim _{x\to -\infty }\left(\frac{a^x+b^x}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$
>
> $=\lim _{x\to -\infty }\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}\cdot \left(a^x+b^x\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$
>
> $=\lim _{x\to -\infty }\left(a^x+b^x\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$
>
> $\lim _{x\to -\infty }\left(max\left(a^x,b^x\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}\le \lim _{x\to -\infty }\left(a^x+b^x\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}\le \lim \:_{x\to \:-\infty \:}\left(2\cdot max\left(a^x,b^x\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$

when $x\to -\infty$
,$max\left(a^x,b^x\right)=min\left(a,b\right)^x$

So

> $\lim _{x\to -\infty }\left(min\left(a,b\right)^x\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}\le \lim _{x\to -\infty }\left(a^x+b^x\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}\le \lim \:_{x\to \:-\infty \:}\left(2\cdot min\left(a,b\right)^x\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}\:$
>
> $\lim _{x\to -\infty }min\left(a,b\right)\le \lim _{x\to -\infty }\left(a^x+b^x\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}\le \lim \:_{x\to \:-\infty \:}2^{\frac{1}{x}}\cdot min\left(a,b\right)$

**Conclusion:**

> $min\left(a,b\right)\le \lim _{x\to -\infty }\left(a^x+b^x\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}\le min\left(a,b\right)$

By the way, I found the following method is also true when $x\to +\infty$.

> $\lim _{x\to +\infty }\left(max\left(a^x,b^x\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}\le \lim _{x\to +\infty }\left(a^x+b^x\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}\le \lim \:_{x\to \:+\infty \:}\left(2\cdot max\left(a^x,b^x\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Without loss of generality, assume $b\ge a$ and use $$b^x\le a^x+b^x\le 2\cdot b^x$$

Comment: Is this the same way as $x\to -\infty$?@Mostafa Ayaz

Comment: Would $\frac{a^x+b^x}{2}\geqslant\sqrt{a^xb^x}$ be efficient here?

Comment: @ClancyZeng, not sure if it **exactly** holds for $x\to-\infty$, but a similar idea (just like this one and based on squeeze theorem) can solve it for $x\to-\infty$

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya, no because $\sqrt{a^xb^x}\le b^x$ for $b\ge a$ and $x\to \infty$

Comment: When $x\lt0$, I think your inequality should be $a^x\le a^x+b^x\le 2\cdot a^x$